# Python linebreak '\n' is not working when I include something at end

Tags: python, line-breaks

The Python linebreak command \n doesn't work for me on Python 2.7 when I include something in the statement, like an int or a numpy array. Is there a way to do this? Here are some examples:

```
print("These \n linebreaks don't work:\n", 1)
"These \n linebreaks don't work:\n", 1

print("These \n work fine\n")
These 
 work fine
```

Comment: Remove parantheses if you are using Python 2.7 since `print` is _not_ a function. This should work: `print "These \n linebreaks don't work:\n", 1`

Comment: Ah, I had switched from Python 3.5 and forgot about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use `print` like a function, import the one from Python3.

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print("These \n linebreaks don't work:\n", 1)
These 
 linebreaks don't work:
 1
```

Now they actually do and you won't have to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Python 2.7, **you can't** use parentheses using the default `print` keyword :

```
print "These \n linebreaks work fine :\n", 1
```

If you use parentheses, it will consider that you provide it a `tuple`, for example you were providing a `tuple` containing `"These \n linebreaks don't work:\n"` and `1`.

**EDIT :** If you want to use the `print` function (like in Python 3), you should import it from the future like shown in [timgeb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36792708/6219612).

Comment: Except that a lot of people would say the opposite: even if you are using Python 2.7 you *should* be using parentheses with print (but you do have to import it from the future first).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that since I'm using Python 3, but thanks for the info